# Getting error :Error(2,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(8,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, database-trigger

My code is like below.

```
create table XXINF_DB_OBJECT_DDL_LOG (
        EVENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
        EVENT_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        EVENT_TYPE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        OBJECT_TYPE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        OBJECT_OWNER VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        DB_USER  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        OS_USER VARCHAR2(100) ,
        HOST_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
        HOST_IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30)
);

create or replace trigger XXINF_DB_OBJECT_DDL_LOG_AUDIT
AFTER DDL ON schema
begin
  insert into XXINF_DB_OBJECT_DDL_LOG values(
    sysdate,
    systimestamp,     
    ora_sysevent,      
    ora_dict_obj_type,
    ora_dict_obj_owner,    
    ora_dict_odj_name,
    ora_login_user,
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS')
  );  
END;
/
```

when I execute get error:

> Error(2,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(8,5): PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

Please use the corrections as below:

```
create or replace  trigger XXINF_DB_OBJECT_DDL_LOG_AUDIT
AFTER DDL ON SCHEMA
begin
  insert into XXINF_DB_OBJECT_DDL_LOG
    (
      EVENT_DATE,
      EVENT_TIMESTAMP,
      EVENT_TYPE,
      OBJECT_TYPE,
      OBJECT_OWNER,
      OBJECT_NAME,
      DB_USER,
      OS_USER,
      HOST_NAME,
      HOST_IP_ADDRESS

    )
    values
    (
    sysdate,
    systimestamp,     
    ora_sysevent,      
    ora_dict_obj_type ,
    ora_dict_obj_owner,    
    ora_dict_obj_name ,
    ora_login_user ,
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') );  

END;
/
```

Comment: Aha, so the mangled message about "Error(8,5)" in the question was referring to line 8, column 5 which was the start of `ora_dict_odj_name` (misspelled). You'd think the OP's development tool would have highlighted it.

Comment: No idea which tool he is using bt i really didnt think that much. i just concentrated more on resolving it.